# How to access an Input file in the shadow DOM using selenium chrome driver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, c#, chromedriver, angular

Has anyone figured out how to access an Input file in the shadow DOM using selenium chrome driver?

at a certain point at the angular.js page a button is clicked and in the function triggered by the event creates this elemnt in the shadow DOM
    `angular.element('<input type="file" accept=".' + h + '"/>');`

I am trying to access the input element so I can bypass the file browser dialog.
I am using selenium webdriver V3 and chromedriver 2.25 which I understood from the release notes supports accessing the shadow DOM.

I've tried:
    `driver.FindElements(By.TagName("input"));`
or
    `object title = js.ExecuteScript("return $(':input')");`
which both returns the input elemnents not in the Shadow DOM

and
    `object title = js.ExecuteScript("return $('body/deep/:input')");`
    throws unrecognized expression: body /deep/ :input

Is there a way to access this element in order to select a file for the input?

Comment: Try this `js.ExecuteScript("return document.querySelector('* /deep/ input[type=file]')");`